# Is it enough to close a Channel or need to close RandomAccessFile as well

Tags: java, nio

I'm working my way through some Sonar Qube reports and fixing things where appropriate. A pattern that some colleagues have employed regarding file access is to create a `RandomAccessFile` instance and get a `Channel` from it. This channel may be returned to the calling code -- whose responsibility it is then to close it. The problem is that by returning a Channel it isn't then possible to close the `RandomAccessFile` object that created it -- so sonar complains.

Is it ok to close a `Channel` and ignore the `RandomAccessFile`. I've looked at the `RandomAccessFile#close()` method and can see that it will close the Channel, but the converse is not true.

Another similar example would be a class the creates a Channel from a `new RandomAccessFile(...)` and later in another method closes the `Channel` but hasn't kept a reference to the `RandomAccessFile`. Should the code be changed to have a field pointing to the file and close that instead? Or doesn't it matter?

Comment: What do the calling code do with the channel? Could the method that new the RandomAccessFile() work with the channel and return the information in a POJO? I think it is an anti-pattern for passing the channel round as closing the file will also close the channel but closing the channel may not clean up the file.

Comment: Closing either closes the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API documentation does not state it explicitly, which may mean there is no guarantee.

However, assuming the `Channel` is a `FileChannel`, then the channel is closed with the `implCloseChannel` method. Looking at the implementation, the parent is closed if it is an instance of `Closeable`.